# Django increment value on submitting form

Tags: python, django

```
class Project(models.Model):
   dept= models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   count = count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.name
   
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            function = self.function.name
            frac = self.fraction.name
            operation = self.operation.name
            if function == 'Production' and operation == '2C':
                self.index = frac * 90
            elif function == 'Vice CTO' and operation == 'Decision':
                self.index = frac *70
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What i am trying to do is everytime i add project  increase the project count of Department. For example 'x' has no project and i add a new project and count will be = 1 then count will be 2. Then department 'y' will add project count will be = 1 for 'y' but stays 2 for 'x' department.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the count as an attribute of project?

Comment: Perhaps this may help you [Autofield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield)

Comment: @EDG956 i need to store Department's project count separate

Comment: But why store that info in each instance of Project? for 1 department, 1 will have count = 1 and another count = 2. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you only want the current count of projects, you could do for a department something like `department.project_set.count()`, without having to retrieve the last project

Comment: department 'x' has 1 project. So count will be 1 for x but 0 for department 'y' that's what im trying to do

Comment: You can achieve that with what I told you, without needing that field in the project

Comment: Think that your projects will all have a `count` attribute, each with a different number (per department). If that's what you want, then use the Autofield. But if all you want is to query the current amount of projects any department has at any point in time, better compute that at DB level like I did or with annotations or what have you

Comment: The only reason I can think of why I'd want that field is to somehow keep some history of how many projects had been created prior to the newest

Comment: I think this is a case of [the XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain the use cases you want to cover

Comment: you can overwrite the __save__ method with def save(self, *args, **kwargs) and create your funct here

Comment: @Carlo i already override save method before  but i dont think i can do it multiple times

Comment: should you share also such save method? should you include that increment as well inside that method? 
also i'd think about the underlying logic 
seems already too complicated given the simplicity of the model

Comment: I have not clear the business logic behind your request sorry, but as a rule of thumb you should be able to write a function to do what you need within the save method.
Looking from above, seems more of a design logic than code logic, are you sure this is the right\cleanest way to get what you need?